# 3rd analytical group of cations

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, analytical-chemistry, identification

If a mixture of Mn$^{2+}$, Zn$^{2+}$, Co$^{2+}$, Ni$^{2+}$ and Al$^{3+}$ salts is dissolved in water, a white dim solution is obtained. I guess that the aluminium and zinc ions hydrolysed and the respective hydroxides are formed. Am I right, or maybe one of them won't hydrolyze so much that the solution becomes dim or maybe some other cation could have hydrolysed, too?

Comment: I'm quite sure that aluminium will produce a white colour due to formation of hydroxide. Manganese, zinc, cobalt hydroxides are probably soluble as they are precipitated in the 4th group as sulphides. Not sure about zinc.

Comment: Okay, I just need a confirmation whether zinc will produce a white hydroxide, too.

Comment: Just looked at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_hydroxide) page for zinc hydroxide. Zinc hydroxide will form a white precipitate but will dissolve in excess acid or base due to its amphoteric character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aluminium and zinc will produce a white precipitate due to formation of hydroxide. Both these hydroxides dissolve in excess acid or alkali due to their amphoteric character.

Manganese, nickel, cobalt hydroxides are probably soluble as they are precipitated in the 4th group as sulphides.

Comment: You mean nickel instead of zinc in the second paragraph?

Comment: @Marko I did mean nickel. Updated answer. Thanks for pointing out the error.